# I want to obtain the position and orientation of objects on ignition gazebo (Fortress)

Tags: gazebo-ignition

I have a question that I would like to discuss with you all.
I am currently using the ignition gazebo fortress and I want to get the position and coordinates of an object on the simulation.
What I want to get is the object set in the  tag in the sdf file that is loaded when the simulation starts.
And I am using the turtlebot4 simulator and I want to know the position of the turtlebot4 urdf.
That simulator is
https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot4_simulator

I am thinking of using the ignition gazebo service, but I would like to know the specific command.